# Which is better: using onclick or find element that triggered the event for handling events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I always wondered which is the better way of handling events in terms of code manageability, cleanliness and code reuse.

If you use the former then say a list of 10 anchor tags with click handler will have something like:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="handleEvent();">Click Me</a>`
`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="handleEvent();">Click Me</a>`
`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="handleEvent();">Click Me</a>`

... 10 times

which looks kind of odd.

With the latter method, using anonymous function, it'd be like:

`$('a').on('click', function(e){});`

Comment: You have answered your own question. With jQuery `on` you can avoid code repetition. Moreover, it lets you make more complex event assigments, even multiple. As for me, I never use `onclick` HTML property.

Comment: I guess so, yes, but it gets a bit hard to maintain code base especially if you're not using a JavaScript framework. As soon as it gets over 1000 lines of code, it's a nightmare searching for an event handler especially when you nest it like: $('.someDiv').find('someOtherDiv').find('li').find('a').on('click', function(){});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day, every event is bound to some element in the DOM. In the case of `.bind`, you're binding directly to the element (or elements) in your jQuery object. If, for example, your jQuery object contained 100 elements, you'd be binding 100 event listeners.

In the case of `.live`, `.delegate`, and `.on`, a single event listener is bound, generally on one of the topmost nodes in the DOM tree: `document`, `document.documentElement` (the  element), or `document.body`.

Because **DOM** events bubble up through the tree, an event handler attached to the body element can actually receive click events originating from any element on the page. So, **rather than binding 100 events you could bind just one.**

For a small number of elements (fewer than five, say), binding the event handlers directly is likely to be faster (although performance is unlikely to be an issue). For a larger number of elements, always use .on.

The other advantage of .on is that if you add elements to the DOM you don't need to worry about binding event handlers to these new elements. Take, for example, an HTML list:

```
 <ul id="todo">
  <li>buy milk</li>
  <li>arrange haircut</li>
  <li>pay credit card bill</li>
</ul>
```

Next, some jQuery:

```
     // Remove the todo item when clicked.
   $('#todo').children().click(function () {
     $(this).remove()
   })
```

Now, what if we add a todo?

```
   $('#todo').append('<li>answer all the questions on SO</li>')
```

Clicking this todo item will not remove it from the list, since it doesn't have any event handlers bound. If instead we'd used .on, the new item would work without any extra effort on our part. Here's how the .on version would look:

```
   $('#todo').on('click', 'li', function (event) {
     $(event.target).remove()
   })
```

Comment: That makes sense. What would you say about my comment above under the question?

Comment: You have to specify the html element, is that an option?  Making the query easier ?

Comment: You can mark this question as answered @steady_daddy

Comment: Ok this answer seems to be matching closely to what I was looking for so marking this as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Second method is preferrable, since we should not be mixing our JavaScript with the HTML. (Separation of Concerns) . This way your code is kept clean.
This also works well with dynamically inserted HTML code.

```
 `$('a').on('click', function(e){});` // Using jQuery.
```

Using Vanilla JS:

```
  document.getElementById("idName").addEventListener("click", function(){});  // Bind events to specific element.

  document.addEventListener("click", function(){});  // Bind events to the document. Take care to handle event bubbling all the way upto the document level.
```

Comment: second option is better because it is more cleaner and separating HTML and javascript code separately